# XCTest output shows error but no error thrown

Tags: swift, testing, error-handling, xctest

I am experiencing a strange behavior when using `XCTest` to check if an error is being thrown. I have a method called `dispose()` that can throw that looks like this:

```
func dispose() throws
```

I wrote a unit test in `XCTest` that looks like this:

```
func testDispose() {

    do {
        // sound is properly initialized during setUp()
        try sound.dispose()
    } catch {
        XCTFail("Error thrown.")
    }
}
```

The sole purpose of the test is to test if an error is thrown when disposing of a properly initialized object that is known to be in a valid state.

The test passes, but in the console I get the following output:

```
Test Case '-[LVGSwiftSystemSoundServices_Tests.SystemSoundTypeTests testDispose]' started.
System Sound Services Error: Unspecified error.
    Message: An error occurred while disposing of the SystemSoundID.
    Code: -1500
Test Case '-[LVGSwiftSystemSoundServices_Tests.SystemSoundTypeTests testDispose]' passed (0.015 seconds).
```

The lines that start with `SystemSoundServices Error:...` are the `description` of the error that *would be thrown* if an error was actually thrown. In other words, an error is created and its description is printed to the console, even though no error is actually thrown!

I can't figure it out. The test passes, no error is thrown, but my custom error message is printed to the console.

[EDIT 1]:

This is the complete code for the `dispose()` method:

```
public func dispose() throws {
    try SystemSoundError.check(
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(self.soundID),
        message: "An error occurred while disposing of the SystemSoundID." )
}
```

And in case it helps, the `SystemSoundError.check(_:message:)` method is a static method on an `ErrorType` that looks like this:

```
enum SystemSoundError: ErrorType, CustomStringConvertible {

    // ...

    public static func check(status: OSStatus, message: String) throws {

        guard status == noErr
            else { throw self.init(status: status, message: message) }
    }
}
```

[Edit 2]: Per @Lou Franco's suggestion, I tried removing the `do-catch` blocks from the unit test, like this:

```
func testDispose() {
    try! sound.dispose()
}
```

I get the same result - the test passes (of course - there are no asserts in it) and no error is thrown, but I still get the error message printed to the console.

[Edit 3]: I've also called `try dispose()` inside of a regular application and no error is thrown, and no error message is printed to the console. The error message is only being printed to the console inside `XCTest`. Very strange.

Comment: Can you share the code inside of `sound.dispose()`?  I'm wondering whether the error is already being caught.

Comment: I added the complete code for `dispose()`, as well as the error checking code that would actually throw the error. I am pretty sure that the error is not being caught anywhere up the chain.

Comment: remove the do/catch/XCTFail -- what happens?

Comment: I removed them, and used `try! dispose()` and got the same result. I edited my question to show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, though it is still very strange. If I initialize `sound` inside of the `testDispose()` unit test, then the error message is not printed.

Previously, my test class looked something like this:

```
class SystemSoundTypeTests: XCTestCase {

    struct MySystemSound: SystemSoundType {
        var soundID: UInt32
    }

    var sound: MySystemSound!
    let frog = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/Sounds/Frog.aiff")

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        do {
            sound = MySystemSound(soundID: try MySystemSound.open(frog))
        } catch {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I stopped using `setup()` to initialize a `sound` variable, and instead I create it inside of the unit test:

```
func testDispose() {

    do {
        let sound = MySystemSound(soundID: try MySystemSound.open(frog))
        try sound.dispose()
    } catch {
        XCTFail("Error thrown.")
    }
}
```

When I initialize it inside of the unit test, no message is printed to the console.

This is a weird bug of some kind, because I've got about a dozen other tests inside the same class, some of which test throwing functions, and none of them acted like this one.

Comment: Report it to Apple then!